# Get mime-type of file extension

Tags: bash, awk, mime-types, gnu

I am trying to make a script that given a file extension (such as 'opus'), it prints the corresponding mime-type ('audio/ogg').
This is so that I can find the mime-type of an inexistent file in the given system (for example, a remote file).

I did try using gawk on /etc/mime.types, but a am a beginner at gawk, and trying to hack with it is difficult to me.

But I do know that gawk is the best solution for this job. Or else, I want a GNU/Linux tool that already does this.

This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -F' ' '$0 ~ /'${1}'/' /etc/mime.types
```

It is made to be used as `./extension2mime opus`

1. I am having difficulties setting the field delimiter as tabs (because I believe tabs are used in /etc/mime.types between the mime-type and the file extension part).
2. I want to match all the columns except the first column. And to print only the first column of the match (precisely the column that I am ignoring). This is done on the /etc/mime.types file, of course.

**EDIT:**

The result of `./extension2mime opus` would be `audio/ogg`.

Here is an excerpt of /etc/mime.types

```
audio/mpeg                                      mp3 mpga mp1 mp2
audio/mpeg4-generic
audio/ogg                                       oga ogg opus spx
audio/opus
audio/parityfec
audio/PCMA
```

Comment: What is the expected output exactly? Only the type (i.e. first field)? Should parameters be treated as regex, e.g. passing `.` as argument prints all lines? How to handle comment lines (`#...`)?

Comment: So just `grep -w "$extensions"`? Or how do you define the "best match"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -v ext="$1" '            # pass shell variable to awk
/^#/{next}                   # skip comment lines
{type=$1;$1=""}              # store and strip first field
$0~"\\<"ext"\\>"{print type} # print type of matching extensions
' /etc/mime.types
```

Note that this interprets your argument as regular expression, so an input such as `.` or `^` would print all lines.

The `\<...\>` regex is to match only full extensions, so that `jpg` won't match `jpg2` or `sjpg` (this is a non-POSIX extension of GNU awk).

Or the imperative approach, comparing all fields with your needle in a loop:

```
awk -v ext="$1" '    # pass shell variable to awk
!/^#/{               # skip comment lines
  for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) # loop fields
    if ($i==ext)     # compare extensions
      print $1       # print type
}
' /etc/mime.types
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to make a script that given a file extension (such as 'opus'), it prints the corresponding mime-type ('audio/opus')(...)But I do know that gawk is the best solution for this job. Or else, I want a GNU/Linux tool that already does this.(...)

Then consider using `python`, it is present in numerous linux distros and has function for that task inside standard library, namely [`mimetypes.guess_type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type), simple script which does output probable type for each argument at command line might be written as follows, let `guesser.py` be

```
import mimetypes, sys
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    print(mimetypes.guess_type(i)[0])
```

then use it following way

```
python guesser.py file file.mp3 file.ogg
```

gives output

```
None
audio/mpeg
audio/ogg
```

`None` denotes unknown, I cut first element from `sys.argv` as it holds name of file from script, I extract 1st element from what `mimetypes.guess_type` as encoding (2nd element) is not needed.